# Which system files are safe to delete?

Tags: files, internal-storage, system

I got only 160MB internal storage out of which 100MB is reserved by android operating system.

Which System files and folders are safe to delete?

For example:

- de, fr, es and it files in `/system/tts/lang_pico/`  seems useless
- `/cust/hw/es` folder seems uselss
- As I have moved many of my application to SD Card, many folders in `/mnt/asec` seems useless

So which files/folders of Android system are safe to delete so that I can make more space for applications

Comment: 3rd party applications do not install to /system, as that's normally/supposed to be read only.

Comment: The data and system partitions are separate, so removing data from /system won't give you any more room on /data. I think you would need to flash a different SPL with a different partition table.

Comment: How can i give more space to data partition?

Comment: What device is this?

Comment: I think it should be same for all devices, perhaps? BTW OS is Froyo 2.2

Comment: Kindly tell how to delete system files

Answer (score 2):

Not a description of all system files that can be removed but the Cyanogen Barebones page gives a pretty good description of which system applications can be removed and how. This may help you clear out some space.
Details here:
http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=Barebones